# Make button. Click Button. DIV with table turns and faces user, but does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

The script and styles are external. Click the button, div with a table in it turns to face user. The div with the table is already angled on its Y axis by CSS. Clicking the button again should get the div and table to turn back to original position.

```js
document.getElementById('larrow').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('PanL').classList.toggle('rotated');
};
```

```css
#PanL {
  width: 380;
  height: 380;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.62);
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 7% 0% 0% 5.5%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(84.5deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#PanL.rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(66deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(66deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(66deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(66deg);
  transform: rotateY(66deg);
}

#larrow {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  margin: 19% 0% 0% 11.5%;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  background-image: url(image);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="larrow"></button>

<div id="PanL">
  <table class="panMid">
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, NOTE: I changed the `background-color` of `PanL` so you can see it working. Only needed to change rotate class to be back to 0deg.

```js
document.getElementById('larrow').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('PanL').classList.toggle('rotated');
};
```

```css
#PanL {
  width: 380;
  height: 380;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 7% 0% 0% 5.5%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(84.5deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  
}

#PanL.rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

#larrow {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  margin: 19% 0% 0% 11.5%;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  background-image: url(image);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="larrow"></button>

<div id="PanL">
  <table class="panMid">
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="owstR">
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
      <td class="dTs"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```